# Item animation of RecyclerView in android

Tags: android, animation

I had a problem when i use animation in RecyclerView, i want to start a TranslateAnimation on a RelativeLayout of all items and setFillAfter(true) to keep the animation when it end, everything looks like good when animation start, but when i scroll the RecyclerView something appear like below:

[[image: 1]]

some item's animation lost:

[[image: 2]]

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final List<Model> DATA = Model.getModels();
private List<RelativeLayout> layouts = new ArrayList<>();

@InjectView(R.id.recycler_view)
RecyclerView recyclerView;
@InjectView(R.id.main_edit_btn)
Button btnEdit;

private MainAdapter adapter;

private boolean isEdit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ac_main);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    adapter = new MainAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@OnClick(R.id.main_all_btn)
public void selectAll() {

}

@OnClick(R.id.main_del_btn)
public void delete() {

}

@OnClick(R.id.main_edit_btn)
public void edit() {
    if (isEdit) {
        btnEdit.setText("Edit");
        isEdit = false;
        for (Model model : DATA) {
            model.isEdit = false;
        }
    } else {
        btnEdit.setText("Cancel");
        isEdit = true;
        for (Model model : DATA) {
            model.isEdit = true;
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.MainHolder> {
    @Override
    public MainHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MainHolder(LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this)
                .inflate(R.layout.ac_main_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MainHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvTitle.setText(DATA.get(position).title);
        holder.tvDate.setText(DATA.get(position).date);
        if (DATA.get(position).isEdit) {
            holder.startAnim();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return DATA.size();
    }

    class MainHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @InjectView(R.id.main_item_title_tv)
        TextView tvTitle;
        @InjectView(R.id.main_item_date_tv)
        TextView tvDate;
        @InjectView(R.id.main_item_content_rl)
        RelativeLayout rlContent;

        public MainHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.inject(this, itemView);
        }

        public void startAnim() {
            Animation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 100, 0, 0);
            anim.setDuration(500);
            anim.setFillEnabled(true);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);
            rlContent.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Is anyone can help me how to solve this problem?thx.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that that view is finished being bound before it is visible on screen, stopping the animation from running. The animation is also quite jarring while the list is moving. It would probably be a better idea to only animate the views when the list isn't moving.